# SwiftUI custom Image Modifier

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a custom image modifier that uses the `resizable()` function, therefore my `content` should be an `Image`. At least, that what I think so.

**Error Message**: *Type 'IconModifier' does not conform to protocol 'ViewModifier'*

```
struct IconModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Image) -> some View {
        content
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Solution

You can just extend `Image` instead.

Used like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
            
            Image("someName")
                .imageIconModifier()
        }
    }
}
```

`Image` extension:

```
extension Image {
    
    func imageIconModifier() -> some View {
        self
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

---

#### Why your solution wouldn't work

You first got the error:

> Type 'IconModifier' does not conform to protocol 'ViewModifier'

This means that your `IconModifier` did not satisfy the requirements for the `ViewModifier` protocol, which if we see the definition:

```
func body(content: Self.Content) -> Self.Body
```

whereas you had:

```
func body(content: Image) -> Self.Body
```

which doesn't work. So next - we will change that to `Content` rather than `Image`:

> Value of type 'IconModifier.Content' (aka '_ViewModifier_Content') has no member 'resizable'

This is basically saying that there is no `.resizable()` modifier for any `View`. The `.resizable()` modifier is inside defined inside only `extension Image`, and so no other `View` has this modifier.

And that is the core problem - the can't access the original `View` (`Image` for what we want) through the `content` parameter in a `ViewModifier`.

This is why I just made an extension for `Image`.

Hope this explanation helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was also looking a bit into why my solution from above isn't working. What's actually happening under the hood that is triggering an error?

Comment: @Pondorasti Added an explanation, hope it helps :)

Comment: Good answer, but it leaves one big elephant in the room. If it's impossible to implement a ViewModifier that only works on Images then how was .resizable() itself implemented?

Comment: @dented42 The built in modifiers are just either an extension of `View`, or an extension of a specific type (in this case it is `Image`). I don't know of any built-in modifiers which are a `ViewModifier`. A `ViewModifier` is a struct conforming to the `ViewModifier` protocol, so you can then use `.modifier(_:)` to apply it.

Comment: @dented42 That was a good question though - it made me think, what is the point in `ViewModifier`, if SwiftUI doesn't often use it itself? [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57411656/9607863) relating to that topic. You can also use it with `ModifiedContent`.