# Change color of SwiftUI give Form section header

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to add a unique style to my app in the most declarative way possible. Coming from the CSS world I am very used to being able to specifically go in and say that `<p>'s` should have specific styling or even `<p>'s` that are within a `div`. I am trying to get similar semantics here.

Ideally I would write my whole interface like this:

```
Form {
    Section {
        LabeledContent {
            TextField("I am a field:", text: .constant("Blah"))
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            Picker(selection: .constant(false), label: Text("")) {
                Text("option 1").tag(true)
                Text("option 2").tag(false)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        } label: {
            Text("Text Field Label")
        }
    } header: {
        Text("Header")
    }
}.navigationBarTitle("Navigation Bar Title")
    .formStyle(.theDefault)
// Very declarative only one style modifier needed. Since every Header text, 
// LabeledContent, picker etc etc is going to look the same I want to make it easy to apply the styling. Ideally automatically.
```

And have that .formStyle(.theDefault) on the `Form` be enough. I don't know if this is obtainable. Thus far I have ran into two roadblocks.

1. I needed to use `.labeledContentStyle(.theDefault)`to style my form sections background with `listRowBackground` that is a bummer because now every time I add a `LabeledContent` I need to specifically call out it should use the default styling.
2. My section headers can't be really be automatically styled by their superviews at. all. Most of the ways I have seen to do this would require me to have duplicated code for every section header.

So I guess my question is. Is there any way for this to just "work". I would love for my code to somewhat look like the above but have my custom styling from top to bottom with as minimal duplicated modifiers as possible. But it seems I can't modify `labeledContentStyle` from my `FormStyle` and I can't go in and specifically change the style of headers.

I would be totally fine if I have to write `AppHeaderLabel("Bla")` instead of `Label("Bla")` as that is better than having to say .textLabelStyle every time I have a `Text` object within my view.

Is there even any way to pull off #2? I would very much like to be able to see my headers.
Here's what my code looks like now

[image: UI Image State. You can barely see header.]

Here is the code

```
enum ColorConsts {
    static let background: Color = Color(UIColor.darkGray)
    static let card: Color = Color(UIColor(hue: 0.6, saturation: 0.51, brightness: 0.18, alpha: 1.0))
    static let textColor: Color = Color(UIColor(hue: 0.619, saturation: 0.23, brightness: 0.65, alpha: 1.0))
    static let accentColor: Color = Color(UIColor(hue: 0.46, saturation: 0.95, brightness: 0.68, alpha: 1.0))
}

struct LabeledControlContentStyle: LabeledContentStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        LabeledContent(configuration)
            .listRowBackground(ColorConsts.card)
            .foregroundColor(ColorConsts.textColor)
            .tint(ColorConsts.accentColor)
        
    }
}

extension LabeledContentStyle where Self == LabeledControlContentStyle {
    static var theDefault: LabeledControlContentStyle { .init() }
}

//https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-form-styling/
struct FormContentStyle: FormStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Form(configuration)
            .listRowBackground(ColorConsts.card)
            .background(ColorConsts.background)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    }
}

extension FormStyle where Self == FormContentStyle {
    static var theDefault: FormContentStyle { .init() }
}

struct AppStyles_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    LabeledContent {
                        TextField("I am a field:", text: .constant("Blah"))
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        Picker(selection: .constant(false), label: Text("")) {
                            Text("option 1").tag(true)
                            Text("option 2").tag(false)
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(.menu)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Text Field Label").fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(ColorConsts.textColor)
                    }.labeledContentStyle(.theDefault)
                } header: {
                    Text("Header")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Navigation Bar Title")
                .formStyle(.theDefault)
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth saying I do hope to write "good" SwiftUI code. So I would probably be good with answers like "repeated style modifiers are just how it's done" if that's truly how SwiftUI should be written. But I am also curious if there are ways to make this more declarative so I can approach writing my UI more in the style it's done above (minimal repeated styling code. Labels,Forms, etc just get the right style).

My suspicion is that I should stop using Forms and Sections since styling them is so important to me and I am already having to be somewhat hacky by using `scrollContentBackground(.hidden)`. Is there a way in SwiftUI to then create my "own" Form/Section classes so that I can write the UI like above but everything just works? I could of course build it with stacks etc. But being able to semantically just use `Form {Section {} Section {}}` is quite nice.

Comment: I thought Section {
        LabeledContent {
    } header: {
        Text("Header")
    } was a section header? You just can only barely see it in my screenshot since the default color for it is so close to the background color. I am trying to create an interface that is dark.

Comment: Anything light. Ideally I have my text color .foregroundColor(ColorConsts.textColor)

Comment: Ah I see, so you are trying to avoid having to say that everywhere?

Comment: Yeah. But for me even Text("Text Field Label").fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(ColorConsts.textColor) made no changes.

Comment: I guess my most urgent problem is the headers not showing because I can't style them. But eventually ideally I would like to write this interface with similar styling to what I have at the top (everything is simple and there is only one style statement) and am willing to explore even complicated options to make that possible. I am missing being able to specifically target sub-view within a view EX: Writing a FormStyle that would also apply a LabeledContentStyle to any labeled content within it.

Comment: Made no changes? Your screenshot clearly shows a bold label.

Comment: Didn't notice. The color certainly isn't applying though

Comment: No it is applying. That is how that color is supposed to look like. Did you write the HSB values incorrectly? Try another color like `Color.blue`.

Comment: Ah you're 100% on point. My apologies. Was applying it to the wrong Text() label. Updating the question.

Comment: Why not make your own Form/Section/Text make them reusable

Answer (score 1):

Note that a lot of the built-in `xxxStyle` modifiers applies the style to the whole hierarchy that is below the applied view, unless there is a subview that already has the modifier. This includes `labeledContentStyle`. If you put `labeledContentStyle` on the `Form`, then all the `LabeledContent` gets the style.

So you can just add `labeledContentStyle` once to the `Form`. You don't need to add it once for every `LabeledContent` you have.

```
Form {
    // ...
}
.labeledContentStyle(.theDefault)
.formStyle(.theDefault)
```

You can even put this in your `FormStyle`:

```
struct FormContentStyle: FormStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Form(configuration)
            .listRowBackground(ColorConsts.card)
            .background(ColorConsts.background)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            // This
            .labeledContentStyle(.theDefault)
    }
}
```

For your section headers, you can make your own `AppHeaderLabel` view like this, as you suggested:

```
struct SectionHeader: View {
    let text: LocalizedStringKey
    
    init(_ text: LocalizedStringKey) {
        self.text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .foregroundColor(ColorConsts.textColor)
            // plus whatever other styling you want
    }
}
```

Of course, `Text` has many initialisers in addition to the one that takes in a `LocalizedStringKey`. It would be better if you just made your own section header *modifier*.

```
extension View {
    func sectionHeaderStyle() -> some View {
        self
            .foregroundColor(ColorConsts.textColor)
            // plus whatever other styling you want
    }
}
```

This approach can be used to "merge" however many view modifiers you want to use, into just one modifier. You can now just say:

```
Text("Header").sectionHeaderStyle()
// instead of
Text("Header")
    .foregroundColor(ColorConsts.textColor)
    .somethingElse()
    .yetAnotherModifier()
    // ...
```

Note that if the styling needs state, you can use a `ViewModifier` instead. See also: [Difference between creating ViewModifier and View extension in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57411656/5133585)

Comment: This is SUPER useful. Many patterns here I didn't think of using. With the sectionHeaderStyle pattern is there any way to get it so that say something I put in in FormContentStyle or at the top level view was able to apply only to the Label views that are headers? Or even only on SectionHeader's?

Comment: @CalebK I don't think "apply only to the Label views that are headers" is possible. But if you want it to apply to your custom view, you should be able to do that with a custom `EnvironmentKey`.

Comment: @CalebK Since `.environment` applies to all subviews, you can use that to do view modifiers that affect the whole view hierarchy. See [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swiftui-custom-environment-values/) for how to make custom `EnvironmentKey`s. You would read these keys in `SectionHeader` and style it accordingly. You can't affect built-in views with this technique though, because they don't know about your custom environment key.

Comment: Can you just add your custom FormContentStyle and SectionHeaderStyle modifiers to the main app struct if you want to make it global?